# scaling fcurve and feeding it to strength of wind force field

Tags: geometry-nodes

Im trying to make wind force field to push on some falling particles to the beat of music.
I can bake the music in a f curve and adjust the forcefield that way.  But I'd like to scale the f curve before it feeds into the force attribute. I thought I could do this in the geometry editor but geometry editor does not let me modify the force field.  Is there another way of doing this.